# React App with Redux

Tags: react.js, typescript, redux

Decided to give ReactJS + Redux + Typescript a try this weekend.
Going to include the code first and then summerize a few questions that came into my mind during development.
Also posting here to get general feedback on what I can improve on.

[The whole project on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-fog-6p34j?file=/src/index.tsx)

index.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App, { PipelineItemType } from "./App";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { EXECUTE } from "./Execute";
import { COPY } from "./Copy";

export const ADD_PIPELINE_ITEM = "ADD_ITEM";
interface AddPipelineItemAction {
  type: typeof ADD_PIPELINE_ITEM;
  data: PipelineItemType;
}

export const UPDATE_PIPELINE_ITEM = "UPDATE_ITEM";
interface UpdatePipelineItemAction {
  type: typeof UPDATE_PIPELINE_ITEM;
  data: PipelineItemType;
}

export const DELETE_PIPELINE_ITEM = "DELETE_ITEM";
interface DeletePipelineItemAction {
  type: typeof DELETE_PIPELINE_ITEM;
  idx: number;
}

export type ActionTypes =
  | AddPipelineItemAction
  | UpdatePipelineItemAction
  | DeletePipelineItemAction;

export interface StoreState {
  pipelineItems: PipelineItemType[];
}

const initialState: StoreState = {
  pipelineItems: [
    { type: EXECUTE, idx: 0, commandLine: "npm run build" },
    { type: EXECUTE, idx: 1, commandLine: "npm run test" },
    { type: COPY, idx: 2, source: "sourceDir", destination: "destinationDir" },
    { type: EXECUTE, idx: 3, commandLine: "npm run deploy" }
  ]
};

let nextComponentId = 0;
function pipelineActions(
  state = initialState,
  action: ActionTypes
): StoreState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_PIPELINE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        pipelineItems: [
          ...state.pipelineItems,
          { ...action.data, idx: nextComponentId++ }
        ]
      };
    case UPDATE_PIPELINE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        pipelineItems: state.pipelineItems.map((el: PipelineItemType) => {
          return el.idx === action.data.idx ? action.data : el;
        })
      };
    case DELETE_PIPELINE_ITEM:
      console.log("Delete" + action.idx);
      return {
        ...state,
        pipelineItems: state.pipelineItems.filter(
          (el: PipelineItemType) => el.idx !== action.idx
        )
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

let store = createStore(pipelineActions);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { Dispatch, Component } from "react";
import {
  StoreState,
  ADD_PIPELINE_ITEM,
  ActionTypes,
  UPDATE_PIPELINE_ITEM,
  DELETE_PIPELINE_ITEM
} from ".";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { ExecuteComponent, Execute, EXECUTE } from "./Execute";
import { CopyComponent, Copy, COPY } from "./Copy";

export type PipelineItemType = Copy | Execute;

export interface AppProps {
  pipelineItems: PipelineItemType[];
  addItem: (data: PipelineItemType) => void;
  updateItem: (data: PipelineItemType) => void;
  removeItem: (idx: number) => void;
}

export class App extends Component<AppProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.props.pipelineItems.map(el => {
          switch (el.type) {
            case COPY:
              return (
                <CopyComponent
                  removeItem={this.props.removeItem}
                  updateItem={this.props.updateItem}
                  key={el.idx}
                  idx={el.idx}
                  source={el.source}
                  destination={el.destination}
                />
              );
            case EXECUTE:
              return (
                <ExecuteComponent
                  removeItem={this.props.removeItem}
                  updateItem={this.props.updateItem}
                  key={el.idx}
                  idx={el.idx}
                  commandLine={el.commandLine}
                />
              );
            default:
              return <div>???</div>;
          }
        })}
        <br />
        <br />
        Debug Output:
        <br />
        {JSON.stringify(this.props.pipelineItems)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState) => ({
  pipelineItems: state.pipelineItems
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<ActionTypes>) => ({
  addItem: (data: PipelineItemType) =>
    dispatch({ type: ADD_PIPELINE_ITEM, data: data }),
  updateItem: (data: PipelineItemType) =>
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_PIPELINE_ITEM, data: data }),
  removeItem: (idx: number) =>
    dispatch({ type: DELETE_PIPELINE_ITEM, idx: idx })
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Copy.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { PipelineItemType } from "./App";

export const COPY = 'COPY'
export interface Copy {
  type: typeof COPY;
  idx: number;
  source: string;
  destination: string;
}

export interface CopyItemProps {
  idx: number;
  source: string;
  destination: string;
  updateItem: (data: PipelineItemType) => void;
  removeItem: (idx: number) => void;
}

export class CopyComponent extends Component<CopyItemProps> {
  render() {
    return (<div>Will copy from
      <input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.source} onBlur={(e) => this.props.updateItem({ type: COPY, idx: this.props.idx, source: e.target.value, destination: this.props.destination })} />
      to<input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.destination} onBlur={(e) => this.props.updateItem({ type: COPY, idx: this.props.idx, source: this.props.source, destination: e.target.value })} />
      <input type="button" value="X" onClick={(e) => this.props.removeItem(this.props.idx)} />
    </div>)
  };
}
```

Execute.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { PipelineItemType } from "./App";

export const EXECUTE = "EXECUTE";
export interface Execute {
  type: typeof EXECUTE;
  idx: number;
  commandLine: string;
}

export interface ExecuteItemProps {
  idx: number;
  commandLine: string;
  updateItem: (data: PipelineItemType) => void;
  removeItem: (idx: number) => void;
}

export class ExecuteComponent extends Component<ExecuteItemProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Will execute
        <input
          type="text"
          defaultValue={this.props.commandLine}
          onBlur={e =>
            this.props.updateItem({
              type: EXECUTE,
              idx: this.props.idx,
              commandLine: e.target.value
            })
          }
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="X"
          onClick={e => this.props.removeItem(this.props.idx)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Questions:

- Is there a better way to render a list of different react components? Currently using a switch as type-guard to get the current component to render.  Coming from a C++ background this feels kinda wrong since you do something different based on the type.
  I was thinking about storing the react component instance inside the array but I read somewhere that this is bad and will most likely cause multiple issues (Unfortunately I can't find the source anymore)
- Should I keep the add/update/removeItem handler together?
  Technically I could dispatch updateItem and removeItem from the child-components, but for me it seems cleaner to keep them bundled together with the addItem method, which means I have to define a callback for the child components.
- In the App.tsx is there an easier way for keys?
  Currently using a counter to have unique keys for the Component List
- When creating a new child component via addItem I need to set `idx` to an arbitrary value, since it is part of the interface. Is there a better way to do this? Just creating a new interface that doesn't include `idx` seems a bit redundant for me.

Comment: Didn't take a look at the whole atm, but what I noticed, your Redux Code is pretty boilerplatey, maybe have a look at `typesafe-actions` package. Further more `idx` is not updated when you remove any item, this seems like an unwanted bug. If I got time, I'll write up a complete review